# VBA extracting data: Getting Compile error For without Next

Tags: vba, excel

I've have been following a tutorial online (https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm). I'm getting a few problems and not sure how to fix them. Basically I'm trying to collect data from a website.

Any tips and idea how to fix the problem?

Thanks in Advance. I entered the code below:

```
Enum READYSTATE
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum
Option Explicit

Sub ImportStackOverflowData()


'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

'to refer to the HTML document returned
Dim html As HTMLDocument

'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "https://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:310761-2018:TEXT:EN:HTML&src=0"

'Wait until IE is done loading page
Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to StackOverflow ..."
    DoEvents
Loop

'show text of HTML document returned
Set html = ie.document

MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerHTML

'close down IE and reset status bar
Set ie = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""

'clear old data out and put titles in
Cells.Clear

'put heading across the top of row 3
Range("A3").Value = "Company ID"

Dim CompanyList As IHTMLElement
Dim Companies As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Company As IHTMLElement
Dim RowNumber As Long
Dim CompanyId As String
Dim CompanyFields As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim CompanyField As IHTMLElement

Dim votes As String
Dim views As String

Dim CompanmyFieldLinks As IHTMLElementCollection

Set CompanyList = html.getElementById("fullDocument")
Set Companies = CompanyList.Children
RowNumber = 4

For Each Company In Companies

  'if this is the tag containing the company details, process it
  If Company.className = "txtmark" Then
      'first get and store the company id in first column
      CompanyId = Replace(Company.ID, "timark", "")
      Cells(RowNumber, 1).Value = CLng(CompanyId)

     'get a list of all of the parts of this company,
     'and loop over them
     Set CompanyFields = Company.all

     For Each CompanyField In CompanyFields  
        'go on to next row of worksheet
        RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
     Next    
  End If

  Set html = Nothing

  Application.StatusBar = ""
  MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you added the references to Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library?

Comment: Ah, forgot to add them. I now get the error variable not defined for Compaines on `For Each Company In Compaines`

Comment: On what line you have got the error? Click Debug and tell us the line ..

Comment: The error is on Ln 62, Col 34

Comment: Spell check that line, you've spelled the variable incorrectly.  "For Each Company In Companies"   How did that not get caught with Option Explicit?

Comment: Not sure, thanks. That's why i added it for mistakes like that. I now have an error on Ln 85 Col 15. Compile error: End If without block If

Comment: There are many very basic problems with the code.  At first glance: The error you got "variable not defined" that was the error from option explicit.  You have two for statements, but one next.  You have an if statement, outside of the loop where you are closing it.  Your internal loop checking the fields is not really doing anything aside from counting the number of fields. You have on sub and two "end subs"

Comment: `For Each Company In Companies` does not have a `next Company`

Comment: What is the exact information you are after? There is only one "company" on that page (Contracting authority). The class you then attempt to use  for parsing covers each section of the  Contract award notice which is text - you are trying to convert this to Long.

Comment: Hi, im looking to get the company name and whether its an SME and get it into a excel spreadsheet. Im not sure how to go about this though. Im fairly new to this

Comment: Name not so hard but how can you tell from what is on the page whether S or M ? There is no SME labelled field.

Answer (score -1):

Error in Ln 85 Col 15 is cuz you cant end if in For... just move it outside For... and it error should be fixed

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i moved End If to Ln 88 just under Next. Now when i run it, i get Compile error: For without Next on Ln 96.